# dynamically extending a type in typescript from passed in class argument

Tags: typescript

Say I have this code:

```
export interface ImportedType {
  new (name: string);
}
export interface Extended<T> {
  foo: (value: any) => any;
}

export function doSomething<T>(Class: T & ImportedType): Extended<T> {
  let name = Class.name;


  Class.foo = function _for(value) {
    // do stuff
  };

  return Class;   // How do I return the extended class?
```

Typescript is obviously complaining that `foo` does not exist on ImportedType.

What is the best way to add functionality to the class argument that is passed into `doSomething`?

Also how can I return the extended type?

Comment: is TypeClass<T> an error? Should it be Extended<T> ?

Comment: sorry, yes, I'm badly copying

Comment: @WilhelmOlejnik fixed, thanks!

Comment: `Class` is an instance of a class? Or you want it to be the actual class which you want to extend with `foo` ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir class is a class, not an instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for are mixins, [this PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13743) explains how to achieve deriving from a generic parameter. There are several changes that must be made to your code and to the code in the PR for your scenario:

- The `ImportedType` interface which represents must be generic in order to flow information about the type created by the constructor
- The PR sample does not constrain the parameters to the constructor at all, and you want to ensure only constructors with a single name parameter are passed, if you just replace the general signature with yours, an errors occurs, I did however find a work around.

Implementation:

```
export interface ImportedType<T> {
    new(name: string): T;
}
export interface Extended<T>{
    foo: (value: any) => any;
    bar(other: T): T; // If Extended also has T in the interface
}
function doSomething<T>(cls: ImportedType<T>) {
    function mixin<U extends new(...args: any[]) => any>(Base: U) {
        return class ExtendedClass extends Base implements Extended<ExtendedClass> {
            constructor(...args: any[]) {
                super(...args);                }
            foo (value: any) : any {

            }
            bar(other: ExtendedClass): ExtendedClass {
                return this;
            }
        }
    }
    return mixin(cls)
} 


//Usage:

class Foo {
    static fooStatic: string;
    constructor(public name: string) {

    }
    public getName(): string {
        return this.name;
    }
}

let FooExt = doSomething(Foo);

var foo = new FooExt("");

foo.getName(); // from original version 
foo.foo(0) // from extended version 
FooExt.fooStatic // Statics will not work unfortunately
```

**Edit**

If you want to add static methods to the class, you can do it like this:

```
export interface ImportedType{
    new(name: string): any;
}
export interface Extended{
    foo: (value: any) => any;
}
function staticMixin<T extends ImportedType>(cls: T) : T & Extended{
    let extCls = <T & Extended> cls;
    extCls.foo = (v: any) => {
        console.log("Here");
    }

    return  extCls;
}
// Usage
let FooExtStatic = staticMixin(Foo);
var foo2 = new FooExtStatic(""); //ok
FooExtStatic.foo(0); // static method
FooExtStatic.fooStatic // also works
```

Comment: `foo` and `bar` are class methods and not instance methods unfortunately

Comment: @dagda1 And you need T in `Extended<T>` to be the class type or the type ? Ex for `class Foo{}` `T` should be `Foo` or `T` should be `typeof Foo` ? Or do you need it at all ?

Comment: @dagda1 added a version for static extensions without `T` on Extended, I can get the type of `Foo` but I can only do it using consitional types in 2.8, if you only need `typeof Foo` in `Extended` that is already available in `staticMixin` as `T`

Answer (score 0):

```
export function doSomething<T>(Class: T & ImportedType): Extended<T> {
  let name = Class.name;
  let extended: any = Class;

  extended.foo = function _for(value) {
    // do stuff
  };

  return extended;
}
```

Comment: Don't think this achieves the desired result, the returned type will not type check very well as it will only have methods from ` Extended<T>` not from the original class

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir @Wilhelm Olejnik what I tried doing was `let Extended: Partial<Extended<T>> = Class;` and then `return Extended as Extended<T>;` but still I think lacks a bit